# scp command fails executing cp

Tags: ssh, scp, cp

I am trying to use scp command to copy the r0.res file from local machine to a remote machine. I entered the following command:

```
scp -v /etc/drbd.d/r0.res root@192.168.1.104
```

and I obtain this error:

```
cp '--' '/etc/drbd.d/r0.res' 'root@192.168.1.104'
```

What could cause the command to fail? Many thanks.

P.S.: I have established ssh connection between the machine and I tested it out by creating the drbd.d folder on destination like this:

```
sudo ssh root@192.168.1.104 sudo mkdir -p /etc/drbd.d
```

Comment: It looks like you typed `cp` instead of `scp`. Are you ABSOLUTELY SURE you typed `scp`? What does `type scp` show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are copying localy with your command, you create file 'root@192.168.1.104', you should run:

```
scp /etc/drbd.d/r0.res root@192.168.1.104:/path/
```

where path/ is your desired destination on machine 192.168.1.104